# ¿Hay forma en android de añadir Componentes a la vista desde la clase?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Necesito añadir componentes desde la clase del Fragment, por ejemplo que si pulso un botón este me añada un TextView al contraint Layout de la vista, es posible?

Comment: Es posible alvaro, recuerda agregar lo que investigaste o trataste, revisa [ask] y agrega màs informaciòn a tu pregunta, si deseas una opinion tienes suficiente reputaciòn para preguntar en [chat], saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si, es posible, te dejo un ejemplo de como añadir una vista a un layout existente.

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.infoLayout);

TextView tv = new TextView(context);
tv.setText("Hola mundo");
tv.setId(Integer.parseInt("5"));
tv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
       LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
       LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

linearLayout.addView(tv);
```

Te recomendaría que intentases elaborar más tus preguntas, e incluir piezas de código ayuda a la comunidad a entender mejor el problema y así ofrecerte mejor ayuda.