# ¿Cómo añadir nuevos objetos tipo layout a medida que el usuario toca un botón?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

mi consulta es la siguiente: hay un botón llamado 'añadir' en un layout vacío, supongamos, quiero que cada vez que el usuario toque el botón salga otro layout con los campos que tiene que llenar (esta parte ya la hice) y que al finalizar toque otro botón para que aparezca un layout (llamémosle objeto) con los datos que llenó en el layout anteriormente.

Mi idea al principio era poner 10 objetos como máximo de tipo 'LinearLayout', ocultar todos y que cada vez que el usuario agregara uno, ir poniendoles '.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)', y poniendo los valores que insertó para dicho objeto anteriormente, pero aunque creo que vaya a funcionar, no creo que sea la mejor opción.

Supongo que lo mejor sería algo así como un arreglo con los datos, un adapter, etc. Si es así, me podrían explicar cómo lo harían? No me llevo muy bien con los arreglos ni con los adapters

Esto es a lo que llamo 'objeto' que el usuario quiere agregar:

```
<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/objetivo_1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@drawable/esquinas_redondeadas"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:elevation="10dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/titulo_esquinas_redondeadas">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/objetivo_titulo_1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="PlayStation 5"
                        android:textColor="@color/blanco"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:shadowColor="@color/negro_semi_transparente"
                        android:shadowDx="10"
                        android:shadowDy="10"
                        android:shadowRadius="6"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                        android:paddingTop="10dp" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_settings_2"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/objetivo_imagen_1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/agua" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                    android:paddingRight="15dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:weightSum="2">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/objetivo_monto_inicial_1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Ahorrado: B/. 100.00"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/objetivo_monto_final_1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Total: B/. 800.00"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                    android:paddingRight="15dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                    android:weightSum="2">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/objetivo_fecha_inicial_1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Inicio: 1/01/2020"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/objetivo_fecha_final_1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Final: 1/01/2021"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <ProgressBar
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/objetivos_progreso_progressbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="50%"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/gris_texto"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Mensaje"
                    android:textColor="@color/gris_texto"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

            </LinearLayout>
```

Ese es el resultado después de que el usuario ingrese los datos necesarios.

El siguiente es el archivo XML que uso para que el usuario ingrese lo que se necesita (que son titulo, monto inicial, monto final, fecha de inicio y fecha final).

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/objetivos_layout_agregar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/menu_obj"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textColor="@color/negro"
                android:shadowColor="@color/gris"
                android:shadowDx="10"
                android:shadowDy="10"
                android:shadowRadius="6"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@drawable/esquinas_redondeadas"
                android:layout_margin="15dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/titulo_esquinas_redondeadas"
                    android:text="Nuevo Objetivo"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/blanco"
                    android:shadowColor="@color/negro_semi_transparente"
                    android:shadowDx="10"
                    android:shadowDy="10"
                    android:shadowRadius="6"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"/>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/objetivos_nuevo_titulo1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    app:errorEnabled="true">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Título"
                        android:inputType="text"/>

                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:weightSum="4">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Imagen"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>
                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/objetivos_Spinner"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="3"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/objetivos_nuevo_montoFinal1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    app:errorEnabled="true">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Monto Total"
                        android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>

                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/objetivos_nuevo_inicial1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    app:errorEnabled="true">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Monto Inicial"
                        android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>

                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Fecha de Inicio: "
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/objetivos_nuevo_fechaInicialText"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Toca para agregar" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Fecha Límite: "
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/objetivos_nuevo_fechaFinalText"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Toca para agregar"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:weightSum="3">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/objetivos_boton_cancelar"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Cancelar"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>
                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/objetivos_boton_instrucciones"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/instruc"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>
                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/objetivos_boton_añadir"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Añadir"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Aún no he hecho el código en el que agrega más de uno, pero lo que tengo en mente es crear un máximo de 10 'objetos' ponerlos todos ocultos y al momento de que el usuario le de al boton agregar, salga la pantalla pidiendole los datos necesarios, luego de que termine y toque el boton crear, aparezco un 'objeto' con los datos que ingreso, y así con los demás, pero como dije, siento que no es la mejor opción.

Añado lo siguiente, espero pueda aclarar lo que estoy pidiendo.
[image: Parte1]
[image: Parte2]
[image: Parte3]
[image: Parte4]

Saludos y gracias de antemano.

Comment: Esta pregunta es muy similar a otra que se hizo hace poco https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/358595/17852 revísala que la respuesta que di ahí debería servirte.

Comment: Gracias por responder @Alex. Pero en tu respuesta a esa pregunta no es realmente lo que necesito, porque el 'objeto' (como yo le llamo) que agrega el usuario es un conjunto de 'Vistas' (es un layout que contiene titulo, imagen, descripción, y algunas más). En dicho caso, yo creo que lo mejor sería lo que dije en mi pregunta, crearlas todas y dejarlas escondidas hasta que el usuario agregue otra pero no creo que sea lo más optimo.

Comment: Jhonny agrega lo que has tratado, tu còdigo en la pregunta, serà recomendable para despejar dudas!, revisa [ask] , saludos!

Comment: Te ofrezco otro enfoque.  Si tienes un formulario, puedes mostrarlo todo en la vista ya visible y el botón de continuar deshabilitado.  Si hay algún error, mostrárselo al usuario para que que lo subsane.  Otra opción es que crees un proceso, por ejemplo, si la consulta consta de tres preguntas, pues tres pantallas, en cada una se pone un dato y en la última se puede hacer una recapitulación por si el usuario quiere cambiar algo antes de aceptar.  El enfoque que sigues de ocultar/mostrar vistas se puede hacer... para mejorar la eficiencia de ese enfoque mírante los ViewStub.

Comment: Creo que entiendo lo que dices @ManuelMato pero creo que no sería lo mejor para mi aplicación. Voy a intentar crear con imágenes lo que tengo y lo que quiero decir, creo que me ayudaría a explicarme mejor.

Comment: Intenté hacerlo como dice @Alex pero me he quedado estancado en la parte en la que el usuario edita un quehacer. Por lo demás todo me funcionó bien, añadir, guardarlo en la BD, eliminar quehacer... pero la parte de editar me está volviendo loco T_T

Comment: @JhonnyL Ahora que hay más datos es más facil ayudar. Por lo que veo tienes dos pantallas, una con la lista de "objetos", y otra con el formulario para añadir estos objetos. Un acercamiento que podrías hacer es separarlo en dos fragments diferentes (o dos activities) y pasar los datos entre ellos, de esta forma no tendrías que estar ocultando y mostrando vistas en runtime, creo que te daría menos dolores de cabeza.

Comment: Hola @Alex gracias por responder. Entiendo lo que me quieres decir, pero en estos momentos estoy en fase 'alpha', por decirlo de una manera. Eso creo que lo haré al final pero lo importante en estos momentos es que me funcione todo, y lo que me falta por hacer es manejar todo cuando el usuario decide editar un 'objeto' o como puse en el ejemplo, un 'quehacer'. Estoy enredado con lo de los ID de los elementos (utilizo View.generateViewId) al momento de eliminar un 'quehacer' y al momento de editarlo. Intenté guardar los ID en la BD pero más me enredé T_T necesito ayuda :'(

Comment: @JhonnyL Entiendo que estés en una etapa temprana del desarrollo, pero gestionar tantos comportamientos en una sola vista te acabará dando más dolores de cabeza, además de los dolores de cabeza de tener que refactorizarlo todo cuando quieras dejar la "fase alfa". Como sea, si quieres darle ese enfoque, te recomendaría que creases una vista a parte que sea la de edición de datos, mostrarías esta encima de la otra, y desde la misma activity gestionarías los datos.

Comment: @Alex Eso es lo que intento hacer pero no sé cómo manejar los ID de los TextView y del layout (elementos que componen un 'objeto' o un 'quehacer'). Como se generan al azar, me enredo al tratar de controlar cada vez que el usuario borre, cree y/o modifique un quehacer en una sola sesión. Si el ID de los elementos de cada quehacer fueran siempre los mismos, yo podría manejar fácilmente los datos al momento de que el usuario quiera editar un quehacer.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que hay una mejor forma de hacerlo y mas simple que añadir dinámicamente Layouts, y es que crees un ListView, con un adapter customizado, y crees una vista especifica para cada elemento que mostraras en List View (item). Esta vista especifica podría llevar todo lo que tu quieras, editText, botones, TextView, etc. Un ejemplo sería algo así:

[image: Items en listView]

Como puedes observar, mi diseño base de cada item se compone de un titulo, 2 imagenes con dos letreros asociados (textViews) y un TextView con un numero a la izquierda.. y es solo un ejemplo, porque tu lo puedes diseñar como tu quieras.

Si te sirve como base, el codigo para generar esto es asi (**item_lista_de_rutas**):

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cv_item_res_tiempos"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        android:elevation="25dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <FrameLayout
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <TextView
                    android:textSize="40sp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="15"
                    android:id="@+id/tvTiempo"
                    android:layout_gravity="center" />
            </FrameLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:id="@+id/layoutRuta"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:text="@string/ruta"
                        android:id="@+id/tvRuta"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imgTipoTransporte"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_width="45dp"
                        android:layout_height="45dp"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/ImageViewCombiDescripcion" />

                    <TextView
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:layout_weight="1.5"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="30sp"
                        android:text="133456"
                        android:id="@+id/tvEconomico" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                        android:id="@+id/imageView_imagen2"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_width="45dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/ImgViewPersonasDescripcion"
                        android:src="@drawable/people" />

                    <TextView
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="30sp"
                        android:text="17"
                        android:id="@+id/tvPasajeros" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Clase Combi**

```
private class Combi{
private int idCombi, ruta, economico, numPasajeros, tiempo;
private String fecha;

Combi(int idCombi, int ruta, int economico, String fecha, int numPasajeros, int tiempo){
    this.idCombi = idCombi;
    this.ruta = ruta;
    this.economico = economico;
    this.fecha = fecha;
    this.numPasajeros = numPasajeros;
    this.tiempo = tiempo;
}

public String getFecha(){return fecha;}
public int getIdCombi(){return idCombi;}
public int getRuta(){return ruta;}
public int getEconomico(){return economico;}
public int getNumPasajeros(){return numPasajeros;}
public int getTiempo(){return tiempo;}
```

}

**Adaptador**

```
public class ListaCombisArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Combi> {
public ListaCombisArrayAdapter(Context context, List<Combi> objects) {
    super(context, 0, objects);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //Obteniendo una instancia del inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    //Salvando la referencia del View de la fila
    View listItemView = convertView;

    //Comprobando si el View no existe
    if (null == convertView) {
        //Si no existe, entonces inflarlo con two_line_list_item.xml
        listItemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_resultados_de_tiempos, parent, false);
    }

    //Obteniendo instancias de los text views
    LinearLayout layoutRuta = (LinearLayout)listItemView.findViewById(R.id.layoutRuta);
    TextView tvRuta = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.tvRuta);
    TextView tvTiempo = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTiempo);
    TextView tvEconomico = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.tvEconomico);
    TextView tvPasajeros = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPasajeros);
    ImageView imgTipoTransporte = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.imgTipoTransporte);

    //Obteniendo instancia de la Tarea en la posicion actual
    Combi item = getItem(position);
    String ruta = "";
    switch (item.getRuta()){
        case ListaDeRutas.TLALNE_AZUL:
            imgTipoTransporte.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.combi);
            layoutRuta.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.azul));
            ruta = "TLANEPANTLA";
            break;
        case ListaDeRutas.TLALNE_AMARILLA:
            imgTipoTransporte.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.combi);
            layoutRuta.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.amarillo));
            ruta = "TLANEPANTLA";
            break;
        case ListaDeRutas.FUENTES:
            imgTipoTransporte.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.combi);
            layoutRuta.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.azul));
            ruta = "FUENTES";
            break;
        case ListaDeRutas.QUEBRADA:
            imgTipoTransporte.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.combi);
            layoutRuta.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.amarillo));
            ruta = "QUEBRADA";
            break;
        case ListaDeRutas.SUB_LECHERIA:
            imgTipoTransporte.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.combi);
            layoutRuta.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.verdeOscuro));
            ruta = "SUB. LECHERIA";
            break;
        case ListaDeRutas.MEXICO_CUAUTITLAN:
            imgTipoTransporte.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.combi);
            layoutRuta.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blanco));
            ruta = "MEXICO CUAUTITLAN";
            break;
        case ListaDeRutas.RANAS_CUAUTITLAN:
            imgTipoTransporte.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.combi);
            layoutRuta.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.azul));
            ruta = "RANAS CUAUTITLAN";
            break;
        case ListaDeRutas.SUB_CUAUTITLAN:
            imgTipoTransporte.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.combi);
            layoutRuta.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.verdeClaro));
            ruta = "SUB. CUAUTITLAN";
            break;
        case ListaDeRutas.CENT_BOSQUES:
            imgTipoTransporte.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.combi);
            layoutRuta.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.naranja));
            ruta = "CENTRAL BOSQUES";
            break;
        case ListaDeRutas.CENT_TEYA:
            imgTipoTransporte.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.combi);
            layoutRuta.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.azul));
            ruta = "CENTRAL TEYA";
            break;
        case ListaDeRutas.SAN_CRISTOBAL:
            imgTipoTransporte.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.combi);
            layoutRuta.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.lila));
            ruta = "SAN CRISTOBAL";
            break;
        case ListaDeRutas.COMERCIAL:
            imgTipoTransporte.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.combi);
            layoutRuta.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.naranja));
            ruta = "COMERCIAL";
            break;
        case ListaDeRutas.INDIOS_VERDES_COMBI:
            imgTipoTransporte.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.combi);
            layoutRuta.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.gris));
            ruta = "INDIOS VERDES";
            break;
        case ListaDeRutas.INDIOS_VERDES_CAMION:
            imgTipoTransporte.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.camion);
            layoutRuta.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.gris));
            ruta = "INDIOS VERDES";
            break;
        case ListaDeRutas.SATELITE:
            imgTipoTransporte.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.combi);
            layoutRuta.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.rosaMexicano));
            ruta = "SATELITE";
            break;
        case ListaDeRutas.SAN_BARTOLO:
            imgTipoTransporte.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.combi);
            layoutRuta.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.rosaMexicano));
            ruta = "SAN BARTOLO";
            break;
        case ListaDeRutas.COSMOPOL:
            imgTipoTransporte.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.combi);
            layoutRuta.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.rojo));
            ruta = "COSMOPOL";
            break;
    }

    tvRuta.setText(ruta);
    tvTiempo.setText(""+item.getTiempo());
    if(item.getEconomico() == 0)
        tvEconomico.setText("S.N");
    else
        tvEconomico.setText(""+item.getEconomico());
    if(item.getNumPasajeros()>=19)
        tvPasajeros.setText("F");
    else
        tvPasajeros.setText(""+item.getNumPasajeros());
    //Devolver al ListView la fila creada
    return listItemView;
}
```

}

**Implementación**

```
private void calcularTiempos(int ruta){
AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this);
SQLiteDatabase bd = admin.getWritableDatabase();
listaDeCombis = new ArrayList<>();
int repeticiones = 0;
String fechaActual = "";
String query = "";
//Si la ruta seleccionada es TLALNE AZUL, TLALNE AMARILLA, FUENTES, QUEBRADA, SUBURBANO LECHERIA, SAN BARTOLO O COSMOPOL
if(ruta == ListaDeRutas.TLALNE_AZUL || ruta == ListaDeRutas.TLALNE_AMARILLA || ruta == ListaDeRutas.FUENTES ||
        ruta == ListaDeRutas.QUEBRADA || ruta == ListaDeRutas.SUB_LECHERIA || ruta == ListaDeRutas.SAN_BARTOLO || ruta == ListaDeRutas.COSMOPOL)
    query = "select * from Tlanepantla order by id";

//Si la ruta seleccionada es MEXICO CUAUTITLAN, RANAS CUAUTITLAN O SUBURBANO CUAUTITLAN
if(ruta == ListaDeRutas.MEXICO_CUAUTITLAN || ruta == ListaDeRutas.RANAS_CUAUTITLAN || ruta == ListaDeRutas.SUB_CUAUTITLAN)
    query = "select * from Cuautitlan order by id";

//Si la ruta seleccionada es CENTRAL POR BOSQUES O CENTRAL POR TEYA
if(ruta == ListaDeRutas.CENT_BOSQUES || ruta == ListaDeRutas.CENT_TEYA)
    query = "select * from CentralDeAbasto order by id";

//Si la ruta seleccionada es COMERCIAL MEXICANA, SAN CRISTOBAL O INDIOS VERDES (COMBI O CAMION)
if(ruta == ListaDeRutas.SAN_CRISTOBAL || ruta == ListaDeRutas.COMERCIAL)
    query = "select * from IndiosVerdes order by id";

//Si la ruta seleccionada es SATELITE DIRECTO
if(ruta == ListaDeRutas.SATELITE)
    query = "select * from Satelite order by id";

Cursor cursorCombis = bd.rawQuery(query, null);
if(cursorCombis.moveToLast()){
    do{
        if(repeticiones == 0)
            fechaActual = getFechaActual();

        listaDeCombis.add(new Combi(cursorCombis.getInt(0),cursorCombis.getInt(1), cursorCombis.getInt(2), cursorCombis.getString(3),cursorCombis.getInt(4), obtenerDiferenciaDeTiempo(fechaActual,cursorCombis.getString(3))));
        if(cursorCombis.getInt(1) == ruta)
            repeticiones++;

        if(repeticiones >= 0 && cursorCombis.getInt(1) == ruta) {
            fechaActual = cursorCombis.getString(3);
        }
    }while(cursorCombis.moveToPrevious() && repeticiones < NUMERO_REPETICIONES);
    cursorCombis.close();
}else{
    Toast.makeText(this, "AÚN NO HAY REGISTROS DE COMBIS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
adaptador = new ListaCombisArrayAdapter(ResultadoDeTiempos.this, listaDeCombis);
lvResultadosDeTiempos.setAdapter(adaptador);
cursorCombis.close();
bd.close();
```

}

Espero te sirva.